# New column with percentage difference of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the columns A and B. I need a new Column (C) with the percentage difference of B like:

```
         A   B      C
2010-01-01   2    NaN
2011-01-03   4   1.00
2012-01-02   2  -0.50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html):

```
df['C'] = df['B'].pct_change()
```

This is equivalent to:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].div(df['B'].shift()).sub(1)
```

Output:

```
            A  B    C
0  2010-01-01  2  NaN
1  2011-01-03  4  1.0
2  2012-01-02  2 -0.5
```